# Follow up to "Is this local martingale a true martingale?"

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-calculus

This question pertains to the topic titled: Is this local martingale a true martingale?

(Find it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110655/is-this-local-martingale-a-true-martingale/189120#189120)!)

"Using the Ito's formula I have shown that $X_t$ is a local martingale, because $\mathrm{d}X_t = \underline{\phantom{b_t}} \mathrm{d} B_t$",

Can someone please explain this opening phrase to the original question to me further? I can not get my head around why $X_t$ would not indeed be a true martingale if it is written in this form (*all* Ito integrals are martingales! (?)).

Comment: In order to make any statements about $\mathsf{E}\left(X_t| \mathcal{F}_s\right)$ one needs to make sure that the expectation is defined.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, not ALL Ito integrals are martingales. For instance, an Ito integral $\int_0^T f(t,\omega)dW_t$ is well defined for the class of stochastic processes $\mathcal P=\{f=f(t,\omega)\mid f \text{ is non-anticipating, jointly measurable and} \mathsf P(\int_0^Tf^2(t,\omega)dt<\infty)=1\}$ and in this case $\int_0^t f(s,\omega)dW_s, t \in [0,T]$ is **local martingale**, which will be square integrable martingale iff $\mathsf E \int_0^T f^2(s,\omega)\, ds<\infty$.

In the case, mentioned above, that process is a square integrable martingale.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make $\left(\int_0^t \sigma_s dB_s\right)_{t \ge 0}$ a true martingale, one has to  show e.g. that its quadratic variation is integrable for any $t$. Use the fact that
$$ \langle \int_0^. \sigma_s dB_s\rangle_t = \int_0^t \sigma_s^2 ds $$
and show that 
$$ \mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^t \sigma_s^2 ds \right) < \infty $$
Keep in mind that it is not as trivial as it may seem, but often true in practice.